# Retrieve record from data extension - apex API call

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api

I need to implement an API call in sales cloud in order to Retrieve data extension's records managed in marketing cloud.
I tried to configure the SOAP API as explained here 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm

However I wasn't able to find a way to embedd this logic in the salesforce apex code.

Could you tell me if there is any documentation regarding this topic?
Do you know if there is a REST API that allows me to obtain the dame result?

Comment: Have you looked at this? might help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78721/soap-api-applying-filter-to-a-retrieve-data-in-apex